# Скрыть операторы в командной строке Linux

Tags: linux, shell

Как скрыть конкретные ключи команды для ввода в терминале?

К примеру если использовать:

```
stty echo
```

Мне приходится вводить полностью команду вслепую.

Так же, рассмотрел вариант алиасов, но мало ли, может есть что-то более подручное?

Comment: Если вы про всякие пароли, то их просто не нужно писать в терминале.

Comment: Почему бы не использовать alias?

Comment: Вопрос не отражает сути то, что вам именно нужно.  Можете расписать подробней что именно хотите добиться? Если "сокращать ввод" то это `alias`  если "что то скрыть при вводе" после ввода   жмите **Ctrl+U**

Comment: + некоторые инструменты имеют свой механизм алиасов (`git`) + некоторые опции можно хранить в файлах, например пароль от базы - в `.my.cnf`. А цель сокрытия какая? Если пароли, то ... попробуйте подрубиться к мускулу через `mysql -u... -p...` с явным указанием пароля, а потом гляньте `cat /proc/{пид-процесса}/cmdline` - пароль будет скрыт: `mysql-uroot-pxxxxx`. Может другие команды тоже так умеют

Answer (score 1):

Используйте alias
В файл ~/.bashrc добавляете строку, на подобии

```
alias update='sudo apt update'
```

> где update - кастомная строка, которую придумываете сами.

Но старайтесь, чтобы она не перекрыла другие имена, к примеру : 'apt' или 'exit' и другие 
А в кавычках прописываете свою строку.
Если вам будет нужен вызов команды с аргументами, то просто прописывайте их после своей команды.
Чтобы все заработало, вам надо дать указание системе подгрузить файл по новой:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```